# Dont want listing in Job manager plugin in wordpress

Tags: forms, wordpress

I have to use a form for job application on one of my clients site.
I'm using Job Manager Plugin of Wordpress. It's very nice and gives all the fields that I want. It has created a page itself and showing the job listing first and after clicking the apply now link it directs to the form.

But I just want to show the application form. I'll list the positions in the form itself. I've checked the settings but couldn't find any option to skip the job listings.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "But I just want to show the application form" do you mean you want to link people directly to the application from a different area? Soemthing like http://www.yoursite.com/jobs just takes them straight to the application instead of a job listing with one job?

After you click the link to get to the application, you are presented with a unique URL. So you're wanting to link directly to that. Right?  If they only have one job opening, this will work fine. But when they add another one you'd either need to go in and change that hardwired code or you need to write a code snippet to get the list. Review the code from the plugin for specific hints. Or post some clarity here for a more detailed answer.

Alternatively, take a look at the "Job Manager" plugin by Gary Pendergast. That may have the option you need.